# How do I populate a D3.js Circular Calendar chart with events from a JSON Array?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, svg

I learnt D3.js quite recently.

I have a JSON array like this:

```
var DataString = [{
        "Year": "2019",
        "Months": [{
            "January": [{ "Name": "Dance", "From": "1-1-2019", "To": "1-1-2019" }
            ],
            "February": [],
            "March": [],
            "April": [],
            "May": [],
            "June": [],
            "July": [],
            "August": [],
            "September": [],
            "October": [],
            "November": [],
            "December": []
        }]
    },
    {
        "Year": "2018",
        "Months": [{
            "January": [{ "Name": "Dance-2018", "From": "9-1-2018", "To": "9-1-2018" }
                //,{ "Name": "Sing-2018", "From": "19-1-2018", "To": "29-1-2018" }
            ],
            "February": [],
            "March": [],
            "April": [],
            "May": [],
            "June": [],
            "July": [],
            "August": [],
            "September": [],
            "October": [],
            "November": [],
            "December": []
        }]
    }];
```

and another array called monthData like this:

```
var monthData = [
        { month: "January", year: "a", startDateID: 1, endDateID: 31 },
        { month: "February", year: "b", startDateID: 1, endDateID: 28 },
        { month: "March", year: "c", startDateID: 1, endDateID: 31 },
        { month: "April", year: "d", startDateID: 1, endDateID: 30 },
        { month: "May", year: "e", startDateID: 1, endDateID: 31 },
        { month: "June", year: "f", startDateID: 1, endDateID: 30 },
        { month: "July", year: "g", startDateID: 1, endDateID: 31 },
        { month: "August", year: "h", startDateID: 1, endDateID: 31 },
        { month: "September", year: "i", startDateID: 1, endDateID: 30 },
        { month: "October", year: "j", startDateID: 1, endDateID: 31 },
        { month: "November", year: "k", startDateID: 1, endDateID: 30 },
        { month: "December", year: "l", startDateID: 1, endDateID: 31 }
    ];
```

Over all of this I have populated a weeks array in my Javascript code with following structure:

```
var obj1 = {            "weekStart": weekStart, "weekStartMonth": weekStartMonth,
                        "weekStartYear": weekStartYear, "weekEnd": weekEnd,
                        "weekEndMonth": weekEndMonth, "weekEndYear": weekEndYear
                    };
weeks.push(obj1);
```

What has made my life miserable is that having all three of the data structures ready and populated, I am confused as to how to draw the individual activities inside the weekly paths of the chart.

What I have tried so far is this:

```
DataString.forEach(function (YearItems) {
            var y = YearItems.Year;
            //console.log("Year:"+x);
            var x = YearItems.Months;
            //console.log("Months:"+x);

            x.forEach(function (MonthItems) {
                for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                    switch(i)
                    {
                        case 0:
                    z = MonthItems.January;break;
                    case 1: z = MonthItems.February;break;
                    case 2: z = MonthItems.March;break;
                    case 3: z = MonthItems.April;break;
                    case 4: z = MonthItems.May;break;
                    default: z = MonthItems.January;break;
                    }

                        weeks.forEach(function (weekItems) {

                            var weekDate1 = new Date(weekItems.weekStartYear, weekItems.weekStartMonth, weekItems.weekStart+1),
                                weekDate2 = new Date(weekItems.weekEndYear, weekItems.weekEndMonth, weekItems.weekEnd+1),
                                eventDate1=new Date(z[0].From),
                                eventDate2=new Date(z[0].To);
                            if ((weekDate2.getTime() >= eventDate2.getTime() && weekDate1.getTime() <= eventDate1.getTime()))
                             {

                                svg.selectAll(".donutLineText")
                                    .data(weeks)
                                    .enter().append("text")
                                    .attr("class", "donutLineText")
                                    .append("textPath")
                                    .attr("startOffset", "20%")
                                    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                                    .attr("xlink:href", function (d, i) { return "#weekArcTF_" + i; })
                                    .text(function (d) { return z[0].Name; })
                                    .style('fill', 'lightBlue');
                            }

                        });

                }  
            });
        });
```

Which gives the following svg chart:
[image: SVG Yearly Calendar Chart]

monthData is used to draw the outer ring with month names, weeks array is used to draw the inner weeks of the month. The data(names of events) for each week should come from the DataString.
I need a way of accessing all of the above data structures in a way that gives the weekly text in the appropriate weeks only and not all weeks.
Here is a link to the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bmkamath2000/d0pe4bjL/3/

Comment: Can you add jsfiddle for your code, would help much in addressing your issue.

Comment: I would like to mention that I have done extensive rewrite of the DataString(JSON) and weeks object arrays and now able to get only the particular weeks events. The way I solved it is by having another field in the weeks array to store the event names in that week. Then I pre-populated that field by parsing DataString array. Now I had everything to draw the chart in the usual way. I now have another problem with rotation of the wheel which I feel I can solve myself. If you feel you can solve the above problem neatly in any other way please go ahead and take a chance to try and answer.

Comment: Whoa... this is the third week and I have learnt so much. For those interested to know, I messed up the dates,weeks, months and years. Now going to use a js library called Moment.js which takes away some pain points from the hard to crack calendar problem. If nothing I might as well answer my own question some day. Fingers crossed.